# Changing textbox backcolor Conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few textboxes in an aspx page. i would like to change the textbox color to yellow if they are enabled. I can do it individually for each textbox. But is there a way where I can get all the textbox collection of a page and check their enabled property and assign the backcolor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery
Assuming they share a common class "textboxes"

```
if (($(".textboxes").attr("enabled")){
    $(".textboxes").css("background-color","green")}
else{
    $(".textboxes").css("background-color","red")}
}
```

or for earlier javascripts

```
if (($(".textboxes").prop("enabled")){
    $(".textboxes").css("background-color","green")}
else{
    $(".textboxes").css("background-color","red")}
}
```